# Joining integer list

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have an integer list that is supposed to represent binary:

```
x = [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
y = ''.join(x[:4])
```

I can't seem to join it, I get 'sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found'

However if I do

```
x = [str(1), str(0), str(1), str(1), str(0), str(0), str(0), str(0)]
y = ''.join(x[:4])
```

I get 'type error int object is not subscriptable' however I am not trying to to access ints.

Anyone know whats going on?

Comment: there is no way the second one gives that error. you must have done something else. run it yourself again.

Comment: The str.join() method joins a sequence of strings, not ints.

Comment: You can also map `str` to the list, `x = list(map(str, [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]))` or `x = [str(x) for x in [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]`.

Answer (score 8):

`str.join` takes an iterable whose elements need to be strings, not integers.

I see that you have figured this out yourself, and your second method does work (the error you've given is presumably from some other code). But converting each `int` to `str` *by hand* like that is absolutely un-Pythonic. Instead, you can use a list comprehension/generator expression or `map` to do the conversion of `int`s to `str`s:

```
''.join(str(i) for i in x[:4])
''.join(map(str, x[:4]))
```

**Example:**

```
In [84]: ''.join(str(i) for i in x[:4])
Out[84]: '1011'

In [85]: ''.join(map(str, x[:4]))
Out[85]: '1011'
```

Comment: please read OP's question again, he's figured this part out himself(second code fragment). obviously something else on his side went wrong.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr Edited.

Answer (score 0):

One can also use functools reduce

```
from functools import reduce

reduce(lambda x, y: str(x) + str(y),[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0])
'10110000'
```

Comment: quadratic algorithm here... Note, avoiding that is precisely the reason that `sum(['a','b','c'], '')` raises an error: `TypeError: sum() can't sum strings [use ''.join(seq) instead]`

Comment: you can do: `reduce(lambda x, y: x + str(y), [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], '')`